# How do add a '...' to the element before a Read More link in a Wordpress excerpt?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am updating a Wordpress website, whose theme I built. I have post excerpts on the home page, when the excerpt is a certain length it adds a Read More link in `<p>` tags, which makes it the last element of the excerpt. However I want the second last element within the excerpt to have a `...` at the end of it when the Read More link is there.

Currently I am using the CSS of `p:last-child(2)` to add the `...` content to the second last `p` element with `::after`. However, the second last item of the excerpt is not always a `p` tag so the `...` ends up in the wrong place.

How do I add a `...` to the last element before the Read More link?

Edit: I should note that I am allowing `<p>` tags and other tags in the excerpt. I want to add the '...' directly after the last paragraph of the excerpt without a line break. But the Read More link will appear a line below the excerpt.

You can view the current setup on my site [iga.yohut.ie](http://iga.yohut.ie) under the Latest News section on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Niall, you can try adding this into functions.php of your theme. Change the three dots and

tags according your needs.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'custom_add_excerpts_get_more_link' ) ) {

function custom_add_excerpts_get_more_link( $post_excerpt ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $post_excerpt = $post_excerpt . ' ... <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) ) . '"></a></p>';
    }
    return $post_excerpt;
}
}
```

Comment: That almost works. But it leaves a line break after the end of the excerpt so the '...' appears a line below the final text. You can see it on the site here: http://iga.yohut.ie/

Comment: I should note that I am allowing <p> tags and other tags in the excerpt. I want to add the '...' directly after the last paragraph of the excerpt without a line break.

Comment: You just need to delete the line break in your excerpt, in the post you're editing, and will fit nicely.